# accessing to Jquery object values in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom

I'm doing a generic function to validate form items. I'm calling it this way:

```
$('#name').validate(20, 'alfanum');
```

Next, in my function i'll do some stuff, but when I try to access the value of the object, it wont work:

```
function validate(size, type) {
    alert($(this).val()); // shouts an error :(
}
```

How can I access the object's value? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to extend jQuery's object to use that syntax? It would be simpler to pass the object as a parameter

```
function validate(obj, size, type) {
    alert(obj.val()); // shouts an error :(
}

validate(jQuery('#name'), 20, 'alfanum');
```

Comment: I don't have to extend the object, it's a very simple and effective answer :)

Answer (score 3):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/melaku/2/)**

Simple like that:

```
$.fn.validate = function(size, type) {
    alert( this.val() ); 
};
```

Read more here: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/